# Discord bot (.js) repeated message timing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, intervals

I've uploaded a custom-made Discord bot with as its main function to send a message every 24 hours. The first message came right on time, but the next one came up several minutes too late. How can I improve the timing, so that it's sent always exactly after every 24 hours?
This is my repeat message code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    var DailyReset = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '___');

    setInterval(() => {
        DailyReset.send("___");
    }, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a [webhook](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/webhooks.html) would be the easiest way. [This comment on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/5r28fr/how_can_a_post_an_automated_message_every_few/dd4sfj1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) shows how to make timed messages with webhooks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking into that.